# How does ie tab firefox-addon emulate internet-explorer?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, ietab

What I'm primarily wondering is when somebody asks me to take a look at their site and I use ie tab, what should I tell them? That I looked at it in ie 6, 7, or specifically tell them that I used ie tab (not preferable as it kind of defeats the whole purpose of emulating ie)?

**EDIT:** that was the original question, but I changed the title to more closely resemble the actual issue at hand.

[ie tab for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think firefox IE tab, as you called it, is a real internet explorer instance put into FF window. So IE version would be the same as version of IE you have installed

Comment: Yes, almost. See the caveat about FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION below.

Comment: It literally just calls mshtml trident engine to do the work instead of gecko.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't emulate anything. It simply uses IE to render the page instead of Gecko. (That's why that extension is only available on Windows, or at least pretty complicated to get running in BSD, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

I only have Internet Explorer 8 installed (brand new Win7 install). IE tab is using the IE7 engine (out of the box). To test, open up IE tab and go here: http://www.thismachine.info/

Comment: Very interesting point, compared to the other comments. Perhaps you are using IE8 compatibility mode?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I'm not using compatibility mode. I have not changed any settings. Out of the box it is using the IE7 engine (both on 7 and back when I have Vista+IE8).

Comment: By default, all non-IE-hosted WebBrowser Control instances use Compatibility Mode by default unless the hoster (in this case, Firefox) opts-in to the Feature_Browser_Emulation FCK: http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it uses the IE version that is installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as the IE version on your PC.  It just puts a native IE window inside of firefox with firefox controlling that specific instance of IE.